# How to add WinXP partition in grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-xp

I have 2 hardisks: one of 40GB with 2 installations of Windows XP (one in FAT and another NTFS), and another hardisk of 200GB with a BackTrack installation, Ubuntu installation and a NTFS partition.

After installing Ubuntu and Backtrack I don't have the boot entries to get into Windows XP anymore. In GRUB I can see only BackTrack and Ubuntu. How can I add in Windows XP entries  and have the option to select from any of my four OSes after booting?

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to recover access to Windows install.
To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

You could then launch it using either :

- the dash (Unity)
- System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Gnome)
- by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

Try "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I couldn't get the Windows partitions available. Have a look at [link]http://paste.ubuntu.com/750526/[/link]  which I got during repair.